# How can I print the biggest number unless one is missing

Tags: java

I have a loop that checks the biggest number so far and adds one to it; but for example 1 2 3 4 5 I press button 6 is created, what if the list was 1 2 3 5 6 and I want it to print 4 so I can get a correct number line then proceed to increase it by one?

EDIT: I should mention that my list has a possiblity not being in order so 2 1 3 5

Comment: put some of your code here, preferably one that shows what kind of datastructure you are using, as well as your loop.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did paste my code in

Comment: This code doesn't print anything, ever.

Comment: Yes this is just the loop that i'm using to generate the number. I print out the number in my table, I didn;t think it was relevant

Comment: Wolf, you get downvotes because your question is not clear. Please be more accurate with your exact question, and more verbose in your explanation.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm trying my best to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check incrementally that the numbers are good:

So say you have an array of int called numbers[]

you could do:

```
int placehodler = numbers[0] + 1; 
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length(); i++){
     if (placeholder !=  numbers[i]) // checks if the next number is equal to the previous  + 1
           break; // breaks out of the loop if it isn't
     placeholder++; // increment placeholder by 1
}

System.out.println(placeholder); // prints placeholder
```

So if the placeholder breaks out of the loop early, it is your 1,2,3,5,6 situation and it would have 4 (succeeds on the loop where placeholder = 3, fails when placeholder = 4)  in the 1,2,3,4,5 situation, it would succeed on all and end the loop with a value of 6.

Comment: The problem was this, is that my list of numbers has a possibility of not being in order

Comment: then do a simple sort on them first

Answer (score 0):

First, I would find the count of your current list. If your list is [1 2 3 5] the count is 4.

Then, I would create a new list that is a range of numbers from 1 to the count => [1 2 3 4]
comparing the two lists will let you see if any numbers are missing, if no numbers are missing then you can add 1 to the current count and append that to the end of the list.

sorting the list before doing any of this will take care of the out of order issue mentioned in the other comment.